# Centering the text in a heading of a title slide using css in xaringan rmarkdown

Tags: css, r-markdown, remarkjs, xaringan

How can I center the text in a heading of a title slide using css in xaringan rmarkdown. Using the below code it didn't.

```
.title-slide h3:nth-child(2) {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 350px; 
}

---
title: "Correlación"
author: "Manuel Spínola"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
  css: mi_estilo.css
  lib_dir: libs
  nature:
    highlightStyle: github
    highlightLines: true
    countIncrementalSlides: false
```

---

````
   ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
   options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
   ```


   # Hola
````

Comment: Could you provide a sample document with one of your title slides.

Comment: How can I do that Martin?

Comment: Copy and paste the content of a minimal working Rmd document into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `absolute` position, e.g.

```
.title-slide h3:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work.  My intention is to center horizontally, not vertically. I don't understand why text-align: center, it doesn't work.